# Getting values from subsections in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core

Say I had a section like this in my appsettings.json file.

```
"FileSettings": {
    "File1": {
      "Schedule": "1030"
    },
    "File2": {
      "Schedule": "1130"
    }
  }
```

I want a list of anonymous objects with values like this, but schedule is null.

```
  {File1, 1030}
  {File2,1130}

  var fileList = (from a in fileSection
                select new {
                    FileName = a.Key,
                    Schedule = fileSection.Where(b => b.Key == a.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault().GetSection(a.Key + ":" + "Schedule").Value
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the children element of file settings like this.

```
var fileSection = Configuration.GetSection("FileSettings").GetChildren();

var fileList = (from a in fileSection
                select new
                {
                    FileName = a.Key,
                    Schedule = fileSection.Where(b => b.Key == a.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault().GetSection("Schedule").Value
                }).ToList();
```